# How can I automatically forward Facebook messages to my email or phone?

Tags: facebook

I can create email addresses that forward to other email addresses.

Likewise, can I automatically forward Facebook messages to either my email or phone?

Comment: You want to monitor someone? :D

Comment: Vague reply: :D

Comment: If you're on Android or iOS, the obvious solution is to install the Facebook Messenger app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click [image] **Messages** on the left side of your homepage
2. Open the conversation you want to forward a message from
3. From the [image] **Actions** menu, click **Forward Messages…**
4. Use the checkboxes to select what messages you want to forward
   [image]
5. Click **Forward**
6. Enter a name or email address and press **Send**

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/116196048465075/).

Also, to push notifications on or off from your smartphone:

Smartphones:

1. Tap [image] (top-left main menu) > scroll to the bottom of the menu
2. Tap **Settings & Privacy** > **Notifications** > **Email**
3. Tap the setting you want to use

Feature phones:

1. Click **Settings** (bottom of every page)
2. Click **Facebook Notifications**
3. Adjust the frequency of your email notifications > **Save**

[Source](https://www.facebook.com/help/103859036372845/).

Comment: This is manual forwrding how we can forward messages automatically.....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: How can I just get an email notification every time a user messages me directly?

Comment: This answer was probably correct then, but as of late 2020 the first "Source" link is broken, and there is no "Messages" or "Forward Messages" where described (or anywhere else I could find).